# Change width of TreeView

Tags: treeview

I'm trying to create a TreeView for my SharePoint page.

I already finished the "main problem" of creating the view but I can't edit the width of the window.

It looks pretty bad now, because it does not automatically increase its width.
How can I edit the width of the TreeView on my main site?

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 1):

I added a script editor to my window and used the following code.

```
<style type="text/css">
/*increase quick launch width */
##sideNavBox
{
  width:250px;
}
/*Middle Content */
####contentbox{
margin-left: 290px;
}
</style>
```